# Typescript return type for nested dynamic object

Tags: javascript, typescript

Suppose there is a function which return the following object.

```
 private static prepareExperienceFilter(experienceLevel: ExperienceFilterType): any {
    const aggregationObject = {
        'lt_1': { $lt: 1 },
        'between_1_3': { $gt: 0, $lt: 3 },
        'between_3_5': { $gt: 2, $lte: 5 },
        'gt_5': { $gt: 5 }
    };

    const condition = aggregationObject[experienceLevel];

    return { 'yearsOfExperience.min': condition };
}
```

How we can define a type or interface for such object?

I've tried union types, but not succeeded.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just use `keyof typeof aggregationObject` as the type for `experienceLevel`. You'd have to move it outside the function though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By moving the static object outside your method, you can reference its type in the function's return type. This will allow you to use a [generic type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#inference) to constrain the function parameter (while also providing IntelliSense inference to the developer using it) and index the return type:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgcwQJwKYLlAluA8gIwCtVhYBeGAbwFgAoGGAcgBsoB9ARkYC4qYASVrw4wAvgBo6DRvlRQA7qlRhObAMw8+-BFF4AGcQKEw1YyfSayFSlWrYBWTZQE7eAJkOCoqXvbNSmHQcnF10YPwk6UQBuOjooAE8AB1QYAFEADxTkLGVgVAAxLFZUZAAVZNSKAGtUBJAAMxhElMb4JDQMbDwiEihY2joGgFcwUhwwGCS0JLg0TOzcscLi72QYAB4ymFQM7zAAEwh0rNKl-KKS8sqAPgAKXcW81AAZVAA3VGZeMoBKXhoFkYCVQcwguAaCzOzwAdABbLBgTQtVBtRAodCYCYEYikADaZQAugNRFQAqBILAKQcsN1JhR0Z0sT1cVA8Y9ocs3p9mMSAmgoMNkJNnMDQchwZDTjlYQikbxqbSJmISXFaBToDA0BBhqw2HqRBRpqhZvNpecVlc7ix2FxftEYAB6R18MVgiFQmXLeGIkJeXhgYZw2TIB0xMRqjWwbW69hBPxGmZzVCei2XNbW+OMe1Ol2ikHuqVPb1yv2uGCB4OlMNhyPgTUxvWI95wZhYA4wRMm5Op57p0rWuBgEBQAAWpTYtQS2YdjoAVAEGEvlyvV2v1xuYAA-He7ve7ugAQWQCCDylgbRRTAAREOR+PkJO6tfGDAsMdh7A4BAIFgEGA4HwZhUigEApjmOA4TkUoYEvSobwNa8YAAHxga8rEUZRVDUJDUPQuRMNsBxcLQ+MXxhO43DUAAWexfhgOdHToIA)

```ts
const aggregationObject = {
  'lt_1': { $lt: 1 },
  'between_1_3': { $gt: 0, $lt: 3 },
  'between_3_5': { $gt: 2, $lte: 5 },
  'gt_5': { $gt: 5 },
};

type ExperienceFilterType = keyof typeof aggregationObject;

function prepareExperienceFilter <T extends ExperienceFilterType>(experienceLevel: T): {
  'yearsOfExperience.min': typeof aggregationObject[T];
} {
  const condition = aggregationObject[experienceLevel];
  return { 'yearsOfExperience.min': condition };
}

const result_lt_1 = prepareExperienceFilter('lt_1'); // { 'yearsOfExperience.min': { $lt: number; }; }

const result_gt_5 = prepareExperienceFilter('gt_5'); // { 'yearsOfExperience.min': { $gt: number; }; }

const result_invalid = prepareExperienceFilter('another_key'); /*
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Argument of type '"another_key"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"lt_1" | "between_1_3" | "between_3_5" | "gt_5"'.(2345) */
```